# Optimal approach for finding a profitable trading strategy to automate?

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, fx, algorithmic-trading, trading-systems

I am currently searching for an optimal approach for finding profitable forex trading strategies to automate. Currently, I just try to combine various indicators and build an automated trading system based on a mere idea. Although I know that nobody wants to share profitable trading strategies for free, I hope somebody can give me a couple of tips on how to develop own trading strategies.

So, basically I want to know if there is a simple process I can follow.

Comment: That question does not fit the purpose of this forum (developing trading strategies). Please check the help center: http://quant.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic